# On smoothness of twice integrated symmetric function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be a nonnegative, continuous, symmetric function from $D=[0,L] \times [0,L]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $L>0$.

Suppose $f(x,y)$ satisfies $f(x,x)+f(y,y)-2f(x,y) \leq C|x-y|^\alpha$ for some $C$, $\alpha>0$, for all $x,y \in D$. $(*)$

Then is it true that $F(x,y)=\int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{x} f(u,v) \,dudv$ also satisfies $F(x,x)+F(y,y)-2F(x,y) \leq C'|x-y|^{\alpha'}$ for some $C', \alpha'>0$, for all $x,y \in D$?

Attempt:

Obviously $F(x,x)+F(y,y)-2F(x,y)=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x} f(u,v) \,dudv+\int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{y} f(u,v) \,dudv-2\int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{x} f(u,v) \,dudv$ and I tried manipulating the limits a little but I can't get it into a form where I can use $(*)$.

I also tried plugging in $-2f(u,v) \leq C|u-v|^\alpha-f(u,u)-f(v,v)$ into the last integral but I didn't really get anywhere.

Comment: What can $C'$ depend on? Can it depend on $f$ and $L$, just not on $x,y$?

Comment: Yes that's right. $C'$ should not change for different points of $x,y$ but can depend on $f$ and $L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boundedness of $f$ suffices. Let $M=\|f\|_\infty$ in $D$. Suppose that $x<y$. Then
$$  |F(y,y)-F(x,y)|= =|\int_{0}^{y}\int_{x}^{y} f(u,v) \,du \,dv| \le LM(y-x) \,,
$$
and

$$|F(x,y)-F(x,x)| =|\int_{x}^{y}\int_{0}^{x} f(u,v) \,du \,dv| \le LM(y-x)
\,.
$$
Thus
$$| F(x,x)+F(y,y)-2F(x,y)| \le 2LM|x-y| \,.$$